# What is the correct way to add space to an HTML table?

Tags: css, html-table, border-spacing

I'm trying to adjust the spacing of a table in a webapp I'm building. I found various properties controlling space inside a table: cellspacing, cellpadding, border-spacing, and of course - margin and padding. What is the difference between those? Should I just use margin and padding which I know and understand, or is it more suitable and correct to use the table specific properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for cellpadding and cellspacing - they are not supported in HTML5 (See: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellspacing.asp).

As for the margin property, it can be used to space the whole table, but it does not apply for the space between cells (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin). For space between cells use the border-spacing property (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp). for space within cells simply use padding.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution is read something about that properties and decide what do you really need:

- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_border.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellspacing.asp

Comment: I did search the terms before posting the question. The W3school articles about cellpading and cellspacing attributes reveals that those are not supported in HTML5 - this is valuable information. Thanks.